# t-sql or powershell to return currently-configured snapshot folder for transactional replication SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, transactional-replication, powershell

I'm working on a script to iterate through all the snapshot folders and do some basic find and replace of the `ANSI_PADDING OFF` bug and replace it with `SET ANSI_PADDING ON`. I'd like to be able to dynamically point to any publisher and get a list of currently configured snapshot folders by publication. I can then filter and dedupe if needed.

I know I can query the distribution database for the default folder but how do I return the currently configured one, if say, someone changed the snapshot folder via the Replication Monitor GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snapshot folder is configured per Distributor.  The stored procedure [sp_helpdistributor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177504.aspx) returns a column **directory** which is the snapshot folder for a specified distributor.

Comment: Thanks, and sp_helpdistributor runs at the PUBLISHER, not the DISTRIBUTOR too